# Converting WCF web service to Java

Tags: c#, java, web-services, wcf

I currently have a web service built on WCF. It's still in its infancy, so, major changes are still possible. I've been thinking on porting it from WCF to a Java-based solution since I'd like to have a Linux-based backend. What would be the best way to accomplish this "conversion"? Any advantages WCF may have that Java lacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could run your existing WCF services under Linux using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com), the open source implementation of the .NET framework.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509536/wcf-support-in-mono) for links to sources of information.

More information on Mono + WCF [here](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF)